# Override __construct Magento\Catalog\Model\Product

Tags: magento2, overrides, construct

I have overrided the Magento\Catalog\Model\Product.

When I create a new function, I can access it with `$this->_currentProduct->myNewFunction()` in my code.

But, in my new function, I need to use dependency injection `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface`.

So I need to create __construct and call the parent.

But my following code doesn't work :

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $metadataService,
        MagentoProduct\Url $url,
        MagentoProduct\Link $productLink,
        MagentoProduct\Configuration\Item\OptionFactory $itemOptionFactory,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory $stockItemFactory,
        MagentoProduct\OptionFactory $catalogProductOptionFactory,
        MagentoProduct\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        MagentoProduct\Attribute\Source\Status $catalogProductStatus,
        MagentoProduct\Media\Config $catalogProductMediaConfig,
        MagentoProduct\Type $catalogProductType,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resource,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $resourceCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\Processor $productFlatIndexerProcessor,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Price\Processor $productPriceIndexerProcessor,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Eav\Processor $productEavIndexerProcessor,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        MagentoProduct\Image\CacheFactory $imageCacheFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider $entityCollectionProvider,
        MagentoProduct\LinkTypeProvider $linkTypeProvider,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterfaceFactory $productLinkFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkExtensionFactory $productLinkExtensionFactory,
        EntryConverterPool $mediaGalleryEntryConverterPool,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface $joinProcessor,
        TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $config = null,
        FilterProductCustomAttribute $filterCustomAttribute = null
    ) {

        $this->localeDate = $localeDate;

        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $metadataService,
            $url,
            $productLink,
            $itemOptionFactory,
            $stockItemFactory,
            $catalogProductOptionFactory,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $catalogProductStatus,
            $catalogProductMediaConfig,
            $catalogProductType,
            $moduleManager,
            $catalogProduct,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $collectionFactory,
            $filesystem,
            $indexerRegistry,
            $productFlatIndexerProcessor,
            $productPriceIndexerProcessor,
            $productEavIndexerProcessor,
            $categoryRepository,
            $imageCacheFactory,
            $entityCollectionProvider,
            $linkTypeProvider,
            $productLinkFactory,
            $productLinkExtensionFactory,
            $mediaGalleryEntryConverterPool,
            $dataObjectHelper,
            $joinProcessor,
            $data,
            $config,
            $filterCustomAttribute
        );
    }
```

I got the following exception :

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Project\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor

Do anyone know what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Try to remove var/generated. It will work.

Comment: Oh... Indeed.. Thank you ^^"